# What is the best way to save a list of SKU in the admin to use in frontend as an array?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, sku

I need to create a list of SKU separated by commas (sku1,sku2) to use them in the frontend of the site as a global variable.  I tried adding it as an attribute per product and I also tried to create a category then loading a collection in order to show the SKU on the page but it seems to be overkill considering I only need it for less than 10 products.  I just need a textbox or textarea where the SKU can be stored and loaded in the frontend.  Probably in the configuration catalog.  Something like the System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Developer Client Restrictions text box.  Since these need to be changed easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System custom variables. You can set custom variables by navigating to `'System' > 'Custom Variables'` where you can set comma-separated text or HTML value also. You can access it in frontend with below code:

```
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('custom_variable_code')->getValue('text');
```

Comment: Let me check this out.  I never used this before.

Comment: Do accept the answer if it works out! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Used this instead: "$sku_var = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('instore_sku')->getValue('text');".  It works great.

Comment: Oops, sorry for minor error there.